# A new entity was found through the relationship - Symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony

I am having troubles persisting one Entity through a form.

My scenario is:

In my index page, I have a simple form that retrieve entities using the EntityType. This form does not have a data class, I am using it just to save a session variable that contains this Entity, and I want it to be insertable in my forms through my App.
Here is the full controller:

```
class HomeController extends Controller{

/**
* @Route("/", name="index")
*/
public function index(Request $request) {
    $session = $this->get('session');
    dump($session->get('empresa'));

    $usuario = $this->getUser();

    $empresas = $usuario->getEmpresas();

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('empresa', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Empresa::class,
                'choice_label' => 'razaoSocial',
                'choice_value' => 'id',
                'label' => 'Empresa:',
                'choices' => $usuario->getEmpresas()
            ])
        ->add('selecionar', SubmitType::class, ['label' => 'Selecionar'])
        ->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $data = $form->getData();
        $session->set('empresa', $data['empresa']);
        return $this->redirectToRoute('index');
    }

    return $this->render('home/index.html.twig', ['form' => $form->createView()]);
}
```

It works as expected, all the data appears in the dump when the page reloads.

Now in another controller, I have a form that persist a Entity related to the Entity that I saved in the dump (its a OneToMany relationship).

```
public function cadastrarRapido(Request $request){

    $usuario = $this->getUser();

    $session = $this->get('session');
    dump($session->get('empresa'));

    $produto = new Produto();

    $form = $this->formFactory->create(ProdutoRapidoType::class, $produto);
    $form->add('cadastrar', SubmitType::class, ['label' => 'Cadastrar']);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){
        $produto = $form->getData();
        $empresa = $session->get('empresa');
        $produto->setEmpresa($empresa);
        $this->entityManager->persist($produto);
        $this->entityManager->flush();

        $this->flashBag->add('success', 'Produto adicionado!');

        return new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('cadastro_produto_rapido'));
    }

    return new Response(
        $this->twig->render(
            'produto/cadastro-rapido.html.twig',
            ['form' => $form->createView()]
    )
    );
}
```

So, when I try to submit this form, i get the following error

```
A new entity was found through the relationship 'App\Entity\Produto#empresa' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: 
App\Entity\Empresa@000000006e7adf9a000000004feede5f. 
To solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this unknown entity or configure cascade persist this association in the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}).
```

I am not trying to update my other entity, so it is not the case of using cascade=persist.
All I want to do is to save the foreign key in the entity I am trying to persist with the object id saved in my session variable.

Am I capturing the object the right way in my session variable? If I use `$session->set('empresa', $data['empresa']->getId());` I get this error when the form is submitted

```
Argument 1 passed to App\Entity\Produto::setEmpresa() must be an instance of App\Entity\Empresa or null, integer given
```

I guess what I am trying to do is something simple, but I dont know if this is the right approach. Thanks for the help

Comment: The entity saved in the session variable has a lot of relationships with other entities, dont know if this is an important detail to this problem..

Comment: Entities in doctrine need to be "managed" by the entity manager.  You can't pull one from the session and try to associate it.  Doctrine will think it is new.  You need to look up $empresa from the manager or possible use a doctrine reference .

Comment: What you advise me to do in this case @Cerad? I need to have a 'global' entity $empresa that will be inserted in a lot of forms in my app, but the user should also be able to change this global variable through a form

Comment: Just pull $empresa from the doctrine database.  You can still store a copy in your session if you want.  You might assume that because you had originally pulled it from the database and stored it that it would work but no.  Doctrine needs you to fetch all your entities on each request.

Comment: Go to http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/hry2/understanding-the-cascade-persist-operations-in-doctrine, scroll right at the bottom of the page and read what it says. So what you will do is, add `cascade={"persist"}` to `$empresa` property in Produto file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***(Note: The Doctrine Relationship is entity to entity)***
therefore the variable **$empresa** should be an object(entity), when you assigne it to produto

```
$produto->setEmpresa($empresa); //$empressa should be App\Entity\Empresa object
```

But acctually you save ***empresaId*** in the session, and that should not work.

What you can do is,

```
public function cadastrarRapido(Request $request){

    $usuario = $this->getUser();

    $session = $this->get('session');

    $empresaId = $session->get('empresa');
    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Empresa::class);

    // look for a single Empresa by its primary key (usually "id")
    $empresa = = $repository->find($id);

    $produto = new Produto();

    $form = $this->formFactory->create(ProdutoRapidoType::class, $produto);
    $form->add('cadastrar', SubmitType::class, ['label' => 'Cadastrar']);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $produto = $form->getData();
        $empresa = $session->get('empresa'); // now this embpresa is an object
        $produto->setEmpresa($empresa);
        $this->entityManager->persist($produto);
        $this->entityManager->flush();

        $this->flashBag->add('success', 'Produto adicionado!');

        return new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('cadastro_produto_rapido'));
    }

    return new Response(
        $this->twig->render(
            'produto/cadastro-rapido.html.twig',
            ['form' => $form->createView()]
        )
    );
```

}

Comment: Right idea but your implementation is still not going to work.  You should consider testing it as it might be important for future work to understand what is going on.

Comment: Thank you Theva, it worked. I saved the entity id in the session on the first form, and on the second form I just retrieve it, find the right entity with the saved id and set it manually in the form submit. The code turned out like this: https://pastebin.com/vbTBM5U8
Thank you @Cerad aswell.

Comment: Thanks Cerad, will consider in future.